An obscure case of Curry-Howard
It is a theorem of the Intuitionistic Propositional Calculus that
$$
(p\to q)\to p = (q\to p) \land ((p\to q)\to q).
$$
The Curry-Howard correspondence realizes this as a pair of operators (for any objects $X$, $Y$ of any Cartesian closed category)
$$
U: X^{Y^X}\to X^Y\times Y^{Y^X},\qquad V:X^Y\times Y^{Y^X}\to X^{Y^X},
$$
with
$$
U(\Phi)=\left(\lambda_{y:Y}\,\Phi(\mathrm{const}_y),\ \lambda_{f:X\to Y}\,f(\Phi(f))\right)
$$
and
$$
V(g,\Psi)=g\circ\Psi.
$$
Has this been investigated? Do $U$ and $V$ restrict to some bijection between natural nontrivial subsets? Are the composites $U\circ V$ and $V\circ U$ idempotent? If not, what are their dynamics? Do these occur in any known context?
Here is one particular case. Let $Y$ be any set, and let $X$ be a set with two elements. Then $X^{Y^X}$ can be identified with the set of all binary relations on $Y$, and $X^Y\times Y^{Y^X}$ with the set of pairs $(S,\cdot)$ where $S$ is a subset of $Y$ and $\cdot$ is a binary operation on $Y$. Under such identification, $V$ assigns to the pair $(S,\cdot)$ the relation $R$ with $y_1Ry_2$ if and only if $y_1\cdot y_2\in S$, and $U$ assigns to a relation $R$ the pair $(\left\{y|yRy\right\},\cdot_R)$, where$$y_1\cdot_Ry_2=\begin{cases}y_1&\text{if $y_1Ry_2$}\\y_2&\text{if not.}\end{cases}$$
On the other hand, if we switch places and take $Y$ to have two elements, then $X^{Y^X}$ can be identified with the set of functionals from the powerset of $X$ to $X$, while $X^Y\times Y^{Y^X}$ can be identified with the set of triples $(x_1,x_2,\Sigma)$ where $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $\Sigma$ is a set of subsets of $X$. Then $V$ assigns to such triple the functional given by
$$
V(x_1,x_2,\Sigma)(S)=\begin{cases}x_1&\text{if $S\in\Sigma$}\\x_2&\text{if $S\notin\Sigma$}\end{cases}
$$
while for a functional $\mathscr P$,
$$
U(\mathscr P)=(\mathscr P(\varnothing),\mathscr P(X),\{S\mid\mathscr P(S)\in S\}).
$$
Very strange.

Where did either the propositional or the CCC version of this arise?  Why are you interested in this?

@PaulTaylor Logicians mostly introduce the lhs as it is more concise, but as a rule then work with the rhs, as it expresses what is actually going on: in a locale, this describes the smallest sublocales with prescribed closure, it being the meet of the open and $w$-nucleus for $q$. In particular, the lhs as a function of $p$ is a nucleus. I would like to understand better the corresponding monad. I believe Martín Escardó did some work on that.

I think saying "the Curry-Howard correspondence realizes this as a pair of operators..." is misleading, as $V$ is not the only inhabitant of that type. Indeed, there are infinitely many inhabitants: set $V_0:= V$ and then $V_{i+1} \langle g,\Psi\rangle h :=  g (h (V_i \langle g,\Psi\rangle h ))$. Now each $V_i$ has the same type as $V$.

@AnupamDas Very interesting! Could these be $VUVUV\cdots UV$? Are they all different?

[Assuming you mean composition rather than application] I don't think the $V_i$'s I gave, in general, coincide with any $V_n' := V\circ U \circ \cdots n \cdots  \circ V$. For this it is not hard to see that each $V_n' \langle g,\Psi\rangle h$ is always in the range of $g\circ \Psi$ (provable, e.g., by induction on $n$, assuming extensionality), whereas each $V_n \langle g,\Psi\rangle h$ is always in the range of $g\circ h$, by inspection of the definition. Of course those ranges could just be disjoint in some models.
